# Limit question $\lim_{k\to 0}\int_0^{\pi}e^{ik e^{i\theta}} d\theta$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

How would you formally show that the following limit converges to $\pi$?
$$\lim_{k\to 0^+}\int_0^{\pi}e^{ik e^{i\theta}} d\theta$$.

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you use Fourier Analysis?

Comment: No I don't think I'm allowed here sorry

Answer (score 0):

*I do not know if this is the kind of answer you expect.*

What I should do is to develop the integrand as a Taylor series around $k=0$. This gives $$e^{i k e^{i \theta }}=1+i e^{i \theta } k-\frac{1}{2} e^{2 i \theta } k^2+O\left(k^3\right)$$ Now, integration $$\int e^{i k e^{i \theta }}d\theta=\theta +e^{i \theta } k+\frac{1}{4} i e^{2 i \theta } k^2+O\left(k^3\right)$$  Using bounds and the famous $e^{i\pi}+1=0$$$\int_0^\pi e^{i k e^{i \theta }}d\theta=\pi -2 k+O\left(k^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: Okay thanks :) Could you just explain to me the $O(k^3)$ ? I see it used a lot but still don't quite understand it

Comment: You are welcome ! This is the Big O notation (look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) that you find (in particular) when you develop in Taylor series. It basically tells you at which order you stop the expansion.

Comment: So it depends on whether you're approaching infinity or zero?

Comment: Take care : the expansion was done around $k=0$ only